# Does systemd dependencies between modules need to be symmetrical?

Tags: linux, systemd, dependencies

Suppose I have two modules: A and B. I would like to start A before B.

1. Is only A config file enough?

```
[Unit]
Before=B
```

2. Is only B config file enough?

```
[Unit]
Requires=A
After=A
```

3. Or maybe dependencies need to be defined symmetrically in both files?

config A

```
[Unit]
Before=B
```

config B

```
[Unit]
Requires=A
After=A
```

What's the recommended and minimal way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one is enough (on any side).

Just imagine that you have Module B for years. And then suddenly you write an addition Module A. On top of that, the B could be an unmaintained module already or Module B is a commercial product managed by some external party and changing its config could be forbidden from licensing point of view.

Same issues could happen to Module A, so you can control only B...

Another problem could arise if you throw into the mix a third-fourth-etc modules. It could become very complicated to maintain symmetric changes.

Answer (score 1):

As White Owl correctly states:

If you define `Before=A` in `B.service`, you do not need to specify `After=B` in `A.service`

This answer provides you with some documentation explaining that.

The relationship between `After=` and `Before=` is that they are "inverse properties".  If `Before=` is the "forward" property, then `After=` is the "reverse" property.

[`man systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Mapping%20of%20unit%20properties%20to%20their%20inverses) describes this:

> Unit settings that create a relationship with a second unit usually show up in properties of both units, for example in systemctl show output. In some cases the name of the property is the same as the name of the configuration setting, but not always. This table lists the properties that are shown on two units which are connected through some dependency, and shows which property on "source" unit corresponds to which property on the "target" unit.

The man page then provides a table with all forward/reverse relationships:

| "Forward" property | "Reverse" property | Where used | Where used (reverse) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Before= | After= | [Unit] section |  |
| After= | Before= | [Unit] section |  |
| Requires= | RequiredBy= | [Unit] section | [Install] section |
| Wants= | WantedBy= | [Unit] section | [Install] section |
| PartOf= | ConsistsOf= | [Unit] section | an automatic property |
| BindsTo= | BoundBy= | [Unit] section | an automatic property |
| Requisite= | RequisiteOf= | [Unit] section | an automatic property |
| Triggers= | TriggeredBy= | Automatic properties, see notes below |  |
| Conflicts= | ConflictedBy= | [Unit] section | an automatic property |
| PropagatesReloadTo= | ReloadPropagatedFrom= | [Unit] section |  |
| ReloadPropagatedFrom= | PropagatesReloadTo= |  |  |
| Following= | n/a | An automatic property |  |

Therefore, setting `WantedBy=` in the `[Install]` section creates a `Wants=` relationship to the selected unit.